# Core Foundations, where is CF_PRIVATE defintion

Tags: c, freebsd, core-foundation

I'm trying to compile Core Foundations Lite Build 855.14 on FreeBSD 10. The Compiler can't find the type CF_PRIVATE.

example...

```
    ./CFInternal.h:124:1: error: unknown type name 'CF_PRIVATE'
    CF_PRIVATE CFIndex __CFActiveProcessorCount();

    ./CFInternal.h:176:1: error: unknown type name 'CF_PRIVATE'
    CF_PRIVATE void _CFLogSimple(int32_t lev, char *format, ...);

    ./CFInternal.h:176:12: error: expected identifier or '('
    CF_PRIVATE void _CFLogSimple(int32_t lev, char *format, ...);
```

Does anyone know where it is defined? Ive Searched Most of the files included in the CF_855.14 folder
'IE CFInternal.h, CFBase.h, ect', Ive Looked on Google and i'm not finding much information on it. I looked at opencflite-476.19.0 and their CFInternal.h has no CF_PRIVATE type, while a search for it in CF_855.14's version of CFInternal.h has CF_PRIVATE 31 times. Any Help Would Be appreciated and have a good day/night.

Comment: i believe it's, #define CF_PRIVATE __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's

```
 #define CF_PRIVATE __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
```